# For team that doesn't use source control - how to track schema changes in SQL Server 2012?

Tags: database, version-control, sql-server-2012

Ideally everyone on my team would check in/out their changes to the database schema in source control. But in practice, this is not what happens. Is there either a very popular 3rd party tool or a detailed dynamic management view, to view schema changes (CREATE/DROP/ALTER) made to a database, and which user account committed those changes?

Answer (score 1):

Look at [DLM dashboard](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dlm/dlm-dashboard/) from Redgate

Also look at the other tools that Redgate provide for database source control and automated deployment.

You can also look at using [SSDT from Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh272686%28v=vs.103%29.aspx). A similar but not quite as feature complete way of managing databases

Also look at readyroll, or consider using an ORM like entity framework to manage database development

Answer (score 0):

You can create a DDL Trigger to track those changes.

Answer (score 0):

There are several 3rd party tools for database source control including [DBmaestro](http://www.dbmaestro.com/) and Redgate which provide solutions that tackle this issue.

You can create a DDL trigger to audit changes. You can use the session context to retrieve the data of who, when and what. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189252(v=sql.105).aspx. For SqlServer2016 there are new methods.

I agree with @James. The first and **most important** step is the mindset of the dba's and developers. Once the people involved are on board, you can see which tool suits you best.

Disclosure: I work for [DBmaestro](http://www.dbmaestro.com/)